# What webcams are known to work?

Tags: 10.04, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What webcam can I buy that works out of the box with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4217/what-webcam-can-i-buy-that-works-out-of-the-box-with-ubuntu)

What webcams work out of the box for 10.04 or Ubuntu?